# How to determine if a div has a specific element with specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I determine if my  div.class has a specific child element e.g table? with a specific class? Is there a javascript/Jquery function for this?

In my case, I want to know if there's already a `<table class="mytable"></table>` inside my `<div class="anotherdiv"></div>`

any suggestions, answers, and comments would really be appreciated, Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
if($('.anotherdiv .mytable').length){
    //exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Search your div for elements with class name "`myTable`". If you have other non-table elements with this class and you would only like to find tables, throw a `getElementsByTagName` inbetween.

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('anotherdiv');
var yourTable = yourDiv[0].getElementsByClassName('myTable');
alert("Your div has " + yourTable.length + " myTable elements in it!");
```